# Cross reference to external file

Tags: libreoffice-writer, cross-reference

I use cross references inside the same LibreOffice document a lot and find it nice and easy to use.

But I now have a document that is so big, that I want to split it into two files: One with my text (that I work on) and one with the supporting documentations (which is basically just 100s of pages of read-only stuff).

So in mytext.odt I want to reference, say, section 2.3 in supporting-doc.odt.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **master documents**. It is not very convenient, but works:

1. Create a "normal" master document structure, eg. a master document containing subdocuments. (You edit content only in subdocuments, and you organise them, style them in the master document, see [the help](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/lo/text/swriter/guide/globaldoc.html).)
2. You create an *anchor* in subdocument1, Insert » Cross-reference » Set Reference » *somename*; save at your earliest convenience.
3. In subdocument2 you reference this as: Insert » Cross-reference » Insert Reference » pick one "Refer Using" (like "Chapter") » you type the previous name in "Name" field (eg. *somename*) » Insert.
4. It will display a reference error ("Error: Reference source not found"), since subdoc2 doesn't know about subdoc1 labels, but
5. In your master document the reference will show and work fine.